# Can't find QGIS App/Folder

Tags: qgis, installation

I have a new XPS 15 9530 running on Windows 11 and when I Install QGIS (tried several versions and I have used QGIS on other machines for years) it installs successfully but I can't find the software Icon on Apps lists or a desktop folder. From the control panel it shows the software is installed. What else can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you use the standalone (.msi) installer or the OSGeo4W installer ? if the later you should find an OSGeo4W folder in rhe start menu with all QGIS related install

Comment: I used the standalone (.msi) installer for the latest stable and a few other older versions. I also tried the OSGeoW installer once and both haven't worked so far. Navigating to local disk C program files there is a folder created but if I try to open any .exe from there including Saga it throws an error.